# Rspec controller tests enexpected _2 in controller name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controllers

So i have this strange error:

```
controllers/tickets_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': 
undefined method `it' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::TicketsController_2:Class (NoMethodError)
```

and my test looks like:

https://gist.github.com/panSarin/4c8c6199fad8da30498d

And spec helper is copied from other project where my controller tests work.

Rspec version is 3.0.0rc and rails version in 4.0.2 .

Any ideas where should i try to fix it?

Comment: do you have another set of specs somewhere that `describe TicketsController` also? if so, rspec has probably just appended the `_2` internally and it is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: well its a good clue, but i don't have ;/